# Rest assured throws ClientProtocolException when the status code is 303

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured, http-status-code-303

In my workplace we are using rest assured 2.9 to send rest API requests, I'm getting a valid output containing both response body and status code even if the status code is 500,402.

BUT the only case this isn't working is error 303 See Other, I'm getting Method threw **org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException** exception and I can't parse the information that way, all the other status codes are returning status code and body, only 303 throws exception. 
The API isn't the problem, because sending the API through post man work as expected, the call is

```
given()
 .body(body.toString())
 .post(url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: **redirects().follow(false)**

For example:
given().redirects().follow(false).body(body.toString()).post(url);